# How should I organize endpoints to be RESTful?

Tags: rest, restful-url

Let's say I have two types of resources I want in my API: `person` and `class`. These two have a many-to-many relationship.

As such, would I expect to be able to interact with the following endpoints:

1. `/api/persons/1/classes` -- list of classes for this person
2. `/api/classes/1/persons` -- list of people in this class.

What is the best way to organize these in my code?

Here are some possible choices I have thought of, but I can see downsides to each one. (Using C#, but my question applies more generally).

```
PersonsController.cs 

[Route("api/persons/{personId}/classes")]
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public List<SchoolClass> ListClassesForPerson(string personId)
{
    //return result of PersonsService.ListClassesForPerson(personId)
}
```

And have the opposite in my ClassController.cs.

The downside to this approach is that now I have a PERSON controller and PERSON service returning a list of Classes... seems icky.

An alternative might be:

```
PersonsController.cs 

[Route("api/persons/{personId}/classes")]
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public List<SchoolClass> ListClassesForPerson(string personId)
{
    //return result of ClassesService.ListClassesForPerson(personId)
}
```

But now I am accessing the CLASS service from my PERSON controller, also seems very icky.

I think I have decided that the route `/api/persons/{personId}/classes` should actually be handled by the ClassController.cs class even though it's describing a resource on a person... but I'm still not sure if this is the best thing to do.

What is the best practice for this situation? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you considered a mapping endpoint, such as `/person-classes`? Also, I would expect both of your endpoints to have the IDs for the other type in the response body. That is, I would expect the response to `GET /classes` would have at least something like `"persons": [ "/persons/6", "/persons/25" ]` in it, either by default or keyed off of a query parameter. Finally, why are you using persons and not people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't waste too much time trying to build the prettiest API ever. I see nothing wrong with using a ClassService inside of your Person controller. If you're going to try and limit yourself to only using services with the same name as your controller, you're going to spend a lot of time trying to work around something that inevitable will not be a huge issue.

And I also think that a service class should just be a helper class when dealing with the subject matter. So if you need to get a list of classes filtered by a particular field, then that logic should be in a ClassService. As long as you think someone else will not be confused by looking at your code, then you're fine.

Sidenote:

The only small issue I see is with the names of your resources. I've worked on an API with similar subjects. I ended up changing *classes* to *lectures*, since class is a reserved word in most object-oriented languages and I switched *person* to *student* since the pluralization of that could get a little tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I appreciate it. (Also, person/student aren't the real entities I'm working with, I just used them as a made up example).